# internationalization of dates

Tags: javascript, date, frameworks, internationalization, translate

does anyone have any good "architecture" for the internationalization of dates? like in english its Monday,  chinese: 星期一, dutch: mandaag, jap: 月曜日

So my first idea is to create some sort of class that stores the strings of Monday to Sunday in 59 different languages. Apparently this isn't scalable at all, imagine now I need to display "12:34 A.M, Monday, 1st Jan 2000" i will then need another translation for A.M, P.M, the months (both long and short forms), the ordinals, etc, etc.

It's too much work, what's the solution?